# How to set default hreflangs for some languages?

Tags: seo, multilingual, hreflang

I want to make a site with different versions for 2 countries, which have the same language. Then I need to do the same for another language.

Basically I want to have 6 versions of the site:

1. UK English
2. US English
3. Default English ??
4. Austrian German
5. Germany German
6. Default German

The question is, how do I define the "default" language versions, for any country with this language which isnt defined already?

I know there is x-default, but I think you can only use that once and it is for all languages and all countries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have a specific locale, you can just specify the language.  Google give an example here: [rel="alternate" hreflang="x"](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en)

> If you have several alternate URLs targeted at users with the same
>   language but in different locales, it's a good idea to provide a
>   generic URL for geographically unspecified users. For example, you may
>   have specific URLs for English speakers in Ireland (en-ie), Canada
>   (en-ca), and Australia (en-au), but want all other English speakers to
>   see your generic English (en) page, and everyone else to see the
>   homepage. In this case you should specify the generic English-language
>   (en) page for searchers in, say, the UK. You can annotate this cluster
>   of pages using a Sitemap file or using HTML link tags like this:

```
<link rel=”alternate” href=”http://example.com/en-ie” hreflang=”en-ie” />
<link rel=”alternate” href=”http://example.com/en-ca” hreflang=”en-ca” />
<link rel=”alternate” href=”http://example.com/en-au” hreflang=”en-au” />
<link rel=”alternate” href=”http://example.com/en” hreflang=”en” />
```

So you could have:

```
<link rel=”alternate” href=”http://example.com/en-gb” hreflang=”en-gb” />
<link rel=”alternate” href=”http://example.com/en-us” hreflang=”en-us” />
<link rel=”alternate” href=”http://example.com/en” hreflang=”en” />
<link rel=”alternate” href=”http://example.com/de-at” hreflang=”de-at” />
<link rel=”alternate” href=”http://example.com/de-de” hreflang=”de-de” />
<link rel=”alternate” href=”http://example.com/de” hreflang=”de” />
```

Comment: Note that you’ve used wrong quotation marks in the HTML (should be `"` instead of `”`).

Comment: Good spot, although that's copied and pasted from Google guidelines!